# Tortoise SVN Making a past revision the new Head

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, revert

I have reverted to a past revision in Tortoise SVN for my project. I want the past revision to be the new Head revision. How do I go about doing that? Updating after the reversion did not change the files that were reverted.

Answer (score 2):

Rolling back to a previous revision is done via a [reverse merge](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.undo).

1. Update your working copy to the latest revision
2. Execute the following: `svn merge URL_TO_LOCATION_IN_REPOSITORY . -r HEAD:PAST_REV_YOU_WANT`
3. Commit