# How can I find out a file's current HEAD revision in Tortoise SVN?

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

I use Tortoise SVN for file version control.
I have a file with multiple commits across time.
The most recent committed version is the HEAD revision, naturally.
I wished to move the file's HEAD revision to a previous revision.
So, I found the file in Windows File Explorer, right-clicked it to open the file context menu, and performed the following operations.

1. Select Tortoise SVN
2. Select Show Log
3. Find the previous revision
4. Right-click the revision
5. Select Revert to this Revision

This worked, given the message generated by Tortoise SVN and the new file in File Explorer.
But when I return to the file log I see nothing changed in the Log's UI that indicates which file is now the HEAD. I assumed it would maybe be marked with a * or in **bold** or have "HEAD" written near it.

I note that having read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41625626/tortoise-svn-making-a-past-revision-the-new-head) post, I maybe confused as to the difference between "reverting to a previous revision" and "changing a file's HEAD".

So, if a file has 100 commits across time and I am regularly changing the HEAD then how can I know at any time which revision one is the HEAD? I cannot find an answer on StackOverFlow or the Tortoise SVN documentation.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You have **misunderstanding** and **misinterpretation** of some *basic* SVN concepts and entities due to pure TSVN-usage without understanding events behind the scene of GUI
- When you apply ["Revert to this Revision"](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-howto-rollback.html#tsvn-howto-rollback-log) action to file, you get modified Working Copy with changed content of file, which you have to commit into repository in order to save produced changes and you'll get **new revision** in repo, which become **new HEAD** (by definition of `repository HEAD`), i.e. you don't "move the file's HEAD revision to a previous revision" technically, you **create new version of file in the new revision** in repository, with file-content identical to some older revision of file